# grails hasMany left join

Tags: hibernate, grails

A problem with hasMany and left joins:

class A { static hasMany = [b:B] }
class B { String key, String value }
This association creates a mapping table AB.

What I want to do is to sort all A objects by the value in B where key = 'someKey'.  If I use an HQL inner join

```
from A a inner join a.b b on b.key = 'someKey' order by b.value
```

I get the subset of A that has b.value = 'someKey'.  Great.  So, I thought that all I had to do is to change the inner join to a left join and get the full list of A, some with b.value = 'someKey', the rest with b.value = null:

```
from A a left join a.b b on b.key = 'someKey' order by b.value
```

However, when I use a left join, the SQL shows a left join between A->AB, and another left join from AB->B.  This is not what I want, what I really want is to maintain the inner join from AB->B, with SQL like:

```
from A a left join AB ab
    inner join B b on ab.b_id = b.id and b.value = 'someKey'
on a.id = ab.a_id
```

How can I do this? I feel I'm missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is me doing the same thing under mysql directly, but you should be able to figure out the same for your needs..

```
mysql> select a.applications_testserver_id,b.name from applications_test_app_servers a LEFT JOIN applications b ON a.applications_testserver_id=b.id where b.name IS NULL;
+----------------------------+------+
| applications_testserver_id | name |
+----------------------------+------+
|                        145 | NULL |
+----------------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete applications_test_app_servers from applications_test_app_servers LEFT JOIN applications ON applications_test_app_servers.applications_testserver_id=applications.id where applications.name IS NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```